# Как обновлять значение на инлайн кнопке в tg до момента нажатия на нее пользователем?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я хочу отобразить на инлайн кнопке количество нажатий на нее всех пользователей бота, но до момента нажатия там всегда 0. После число меняется, но не видно, сколько людей нажали на нее после тебя.
Буду очень благодарен за совет, битый час пытаюсь разобраться не выходит!

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data.startswith('button_'))
async def handle_button_click(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    button_id = query.data.split('_')[1]
    user_id = query.from_user.id
    username = query.from_user.username

    if button_id in button_states:
        button_state = button_states[button_id]
        users = button_state.get('users', {})
        if user_id not in users:
            users[user_id] = username
            button_state['clicks'] += 1

            # Обновление текста кнопки с учетом нового значения
            button_text = f"{button_state['clicks']}/{button_state['total_clicks']}"
            button = InlineKeyboardButton(button_text, callback_data=query.data)

            await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id,
                                                reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[button]]))
            await query.answer()
            if button_state['clicks'] >= button_state['total_clicks']:
                await notify_admin(button_id)
```

Comment: Обновить кнопку у всех пользователей